# EscPos printer events in java

Tags: java, printing

I want to write a POS printer class in java. Everything seems simple with the low ESCPOS coding but i have a question about printer events.
How can I understand if the printer is in error or the paper roll ends? I read the ESCPOS command reference and every command is (obviously) uni-directional to printer.
For example i can not print a receipt if the paper ends and if this happends my application must know and stop logging cash issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i remember paper out and other basic events are signaled with an (hardware-)event. You have to add an event-listener to your port (ParallelPortEventListener or SerialPortEventListener) to retrieve these events.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/ParallelPortEventListener.html

Comment: I think this class belongs to the java printing api. The printer api uses system printer drivers which could use vendor specific bidirectional commands, which returns more state information then the hardware pins. If you want to write your own vendor independed driver you won't get more information then the hardware events.

Comment: Ooops, I found an escpos specification with description of a bidirectional parallel mode: http://www.scribd.com/doc/26547463/ESC-POS-Command-Guide#outer_page_217  I didn't need this for my very basic printer driver. So you could have to check the inputstream for the error codes.

Comment: Ok, I'm using a USB driver, do you think can be the same?

Comment: What do you mean with USB driver? Do you already have a POS Driver? Or is your printer connected with a USB to serial/parallel converter? Or do you want to connect to a printer direct via USB?

Comment: My printer has a USB interface http://www.bixolon.com/_eng/products/product_form.asp?uid=1 
I can not understand if this has a paraller-usb module inside the printer or it is a pure usb. I'm working on datasheet

Comment: The specs reads, as if USB is standard and seriell, parallel or Network is optional. With USB you're out of luck with 'standard' Java. Some time ago i wrote a JNI Interface for USB with libusb, but i can't provide you with the code. Maybe there are other USB solutions for java out there. The other three interface types can be reached with java.

Comment: I think it is very bad that jvm can not know the printer status... i tried to switch printer off and java let me print many times without any excpetion... I have choice?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are exactly doing. Do you write your own driver from scratch with parallel and seriel port? Or do you use the java printing api with an installed windows/linux printer driver?

Comment: I tried to use javaprint api on windows/linux printer and i see it doesn't work very well: printerstatus is upgradaed just during printing job. For example the queuejobcount attribute is not upgraded very often and AcceptingJobs attribute works only without printer spooler. Now i'm looking for a raw COM dialog, seems to be the only way.

Comment: Maybe your printer is epson compatible, then you could use an existing javapos printing driver https://download.epson-biz.com/?service=pos  (Download only for registered users) Bixolon offers usb-com drivers for your raw COM Dialog. But it offers OPos Drivers (for .NET) also. Maybe it can deliver JPos drivers as well, if you ask them?

Comment: I sent a tecnical support request... I will post their answer. Thank you